# Angular 2 - How to validate form?

Tags: angular

I have this form

```
@Component({
    template: `
        <form [formGroup]="formGroup" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" novalidate>
            <input name="detail" id="detail" formControlName="detail"></input>
            <div *ngIf="formGroup.controls['detail'].dirty && formGroup.controls['detail'].invalid">This is required</div>
            <button type="submit" >Post</button>
        </form>
    `,
})
export class CreateDiscussionComponent {
    formGroup: FormGroup;
    submitted: boolean = false;
    constructor(
    ) {
        this.formGroup = new FormGroup({
            detail: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2) ]),
        });
    }
    onSubmit(): void {
        this.submitted = true;
        console.log( this.submitted)
    }
}
```

what it does is, submit the form when I click submit or enter.

Problem: when I submit empty value, it will allow submitting. Which is bad.

It should not allow and show the error.

Comment: To use multiple validations use [Validators.compose](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/Validators-class.html#!#compose-anchor).

Comment: @SabbirRahman just put into array, form builder will create validator compose for you.

Answer (score 3):

You need `Validators.compose`. Try following example. And also adding `[disabled]="!form.valid"` to the submit button would be nice.

**myform.html**

```
<div>
    <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form.value)">
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="zipCode" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Zip Code</label>
            <input [formControl]="zipCode" type="text" class="form-control" id="zipCode" placeholder="Enter your Zip Code">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <button [disabled]="!form.valid" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Request</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

**myform.ts**

```
    import {Component, ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core';
    import {FormGroup, AbstractControl, FormBuilder, Validators} from '@angular/forms';

    @Component({
        selector: 'myform',
        encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
        template: require('./myform.html')
    })
    export class MyForm {
        public form:FormGroup;
        public zipCode:AbstractControl;
        public submitted:boolean = false;

        constructor(fb:FormBuilder) {
            this.form = fb.group({
                'zipCode': ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)])]
            });
            this.zipCode = this.form.controls['zipCode'];
        }

        public onSubmit(values:Object):void {
            this.submitted = true;
            if (this.form.valid) {
                console.log("FORM VALUES: "+values);
            }
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

your false `<input name="detail" id="detail" formControlName="detail"></input>`, input is void element, don't put closing tag.

btw, you have 2 validators, you need spread error messages:

Online demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/PVndhkpyfY6s1iq5RPsY?p=preview

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <form [formGroup]="formGroup" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" novalidate>
      <input name="detail" id="detail" formControlName="detail">
      <div *ngIf="formGroup.get('detail').dirty && formGroup.get('detail').hasError('required')">This is required</div>
      <div *ngIf="formGroup.get('detail').dirty && formGroup.get('detail').hasError('minlength')">
        This field requires min length: {{ formGroup.get('detail').errors.minlength?.requiredLength }}, 
        actual length: {{ formGroup.get('detail').errors.minlength?.actualLength }}
      </div>
      <div><button type="submit" [disabled]="formGroup.invalid">Post</button></div>
    </form>
  `
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  formGroup: FormGroup;
    submitted: boolean = false;
    constructor(
    ) {
    this.formGroup = new FormGroup({
        detail: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2) ]),
    });
  }
  onSubmit(): void {
    console.log(this.formGroup);
      this.submitted = true;
     if (this.formGroup.valid) {
        console.log( this.submitted);
        // do submit form data to server
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Find very easy code below:
HTML CODE

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4" >
<form name="signup_form" (ngSubmit)="fs.form.valid && signup(fs);" #fs="ngForm" novalidate>
<div class="formbox">
<div class="inputbox">
<div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{ 'has-error': fs.submitted && !fullname.valid }">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name" name="fullname" [(ngModel)]="user.fullName" minlength="6" #fullname="ngModel" required pattern="^[A-Za-z ]+$"/>
<div *ngIf="fs.submitted && !fullname.valid" class="help-block">Full Name is required and must be a valid name</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{ 'has-error': fs.submitted && !email.valid }">
<input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" [(ngModel)]="user.email" #email="ngModel" pattern="^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$" required/>
<div *ngIf="fs.submitted && !email.valid" class="help-block">Invalid Email</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone_number" id="phone_number" placeholder="Phone No." [(ngModel)]="user.phone" maxlength="12" minlength="10" #phone="ngModel" required/>
<div *ngIf="fs.submitted && !phone.valid" class="help-block">Enter valid phone</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{ 'has-error': fs.submitted && !password.valid }">
<input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="user_password" placeholder="Password" [(ngModel)]="user.password" #password="ngModel" required/><!--pattern="^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?!.*\s).{6,12}$" -->
<div *ngIf="fs.submitted && !password.valid && (password.touched && password.errors?.required)" class="help-block">Password is required and must be atleast six characters long.</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<input type="password" class="form-control" name="confirm_password" id="confirm_password" placeholder="Confirm Password" [(ngModel)]="confirm_password" #confirmPassword="ngModel" required appConfirmEqualValidator='password'/>
<div *ngIf="fs.submitted && (confirmPassword.touched && confirmPassword.errors?.notEqual && !confirmPassword.errors?.required)" class="help-block" >Password Mismatch</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<div class="checkboxrow">
<input type="checkbox" id="test1" name="cb" #cb="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="user.cb" [required]="user.cb==null">
<label for="test1" control-labekl>Agree with terms and conditions</label>
<div *ngIf="fs.submitted && !cb.valid" class="help-block" >Please agree with terms and conditions</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<span style="text-align: center;color: #a94442">{{errorMsg}}</span>
<span style="text-align: center;color: #28a745">{{sucsMsg}}</span>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary signin">Sign Up <span class="arrowbtn"><span class="fa fa-arrow-right"></span></span></button>
</div>
</div>
<div class="registerrow text-center">Already have an account ? <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="loginshow">Login here !</a></div>
</div>
</form>
</div>
```

Code of ts file:

```
import { Validator,NG_VALIDATORS, AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { Directive, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
selector:'[appConfirmEqualValidator]',
providers: [{
provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
useExisting: ConfirmEqualValidatorDirective,
multi: true
}]
})

export class ConfirmEqualValidatorDirective implements Validator {
@Input() appConfirmEqualValidator: string;

validate(control: AbstractControl):{[key:string]: any} |null {
const controlToCompare = control.parent.get(this.appConfirmEqualValidator);
if(controlToCompare && controlToCompare.value !==control.value){
return { 'notEqual': true}
}
return null;
}
}
```